# Android Path - get coordinates of a specific point by X axis value

Tags: java, android, graphics

For example consider this code:

```
Path path = new Path();

    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(1, 120);
    path.lineTo(2, 30);
    path.lineTo(3, 40);
```

After that, transformation is applied to that path (path.transform(matrix)).

How to get new coordinate of that points? 
 Using PathMeasure, will not give any valid results. For example:

```
 pm.getPosTan(pm.getLength() * 0.25f, coordinates, null);
```

By using 0.25 i was intended to get that -  (1, 120) (without transformation), but pm.getLength() is related to path length and not axis length...

So how to get point from Path by specifying it's X axis value???

Comment: did you found the answer?